# Как в React сделать так, чтобы элементу в методе .map передавался разный класс в зависимости от условия

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, scss

Мы делаем приложение с Расписанием. У нас есть массив с предметами и мы делаем метод map, куда передаем объекты из этого массива. Нужно передавать разные классы в зависимости от условия. А именно передавать активный класс элементу который удовлетворяет условию. Условие: если текущее время входит в промежуток между началом и концом пары. То добавляем активный класс. А остальные пары должны быть с дефолтным классом.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import styles from './Schedule.module.scss';

export const SchedulePairs = () => {
    const pairs = [
        {
            day: 'Понедельник 1 сентября',
            timeStart: '08:30',
            timeEnd: '10:00',
            time: '08:30-10:00',
            type: 'Лабораторная',
            name: 'Программирование',
            teacher: 'Замятин В.М.',
            classRoom: 'Д-508',
            group: 1,
        },
        {
            day: 'Понедельник 1 сентября',
            timeStart: '10:10',
            timeEnd: '11:40',
            type: 'Лекция',
            name: 'Программирование',
            teacher: 'Димов А.В.',
            classRoom: 'Д-521',
            group: 1,
        },
        {
            day: 'Понедельник 1 сентября',
            timeStart: '12:10',
            timeEnd: '13:40',
            type: 'Практика',
            name: 'ООП',
            teacher: 'Молчанова Е.И.',
            classRoom: 'Д-518',
            group: 1,
        },
        {
            day: 'Понедельник 1 сентября',
            timeStart: '13:50',
            timeEnd: '15:20',
            type: 'Лабораторная',
            name: 'ООП',
            teacher: 'Молчанова Е.И.',
            classRoom: 'Д-501',
            group: 2,
        },
        {
            day: 'Понедельник 1 сентября',
            timeStart: '15:30',
            timeEnd: '17:00',
            type: 'Лабораторная',
            name: 'Программирование',
            classRoom: 'Д-508',
            teacher: 'Замятин В.М.',
            group: 2,
        },
        {
            day: 'Понедельник 1 сентября',
            timeStart: '17:10',
            timeEnd: '18:40',
            type: 'Практика',
            name: 'ООП',
            teacher: 'Молчанова Е.И.',
            classRoom: 'Д-501',
            group: 2,
        },
    ];

    const [showSchedule, setShowSchedule] = useState(true);
    const [showInfo, setShowInfo] = useState(false);
    const [currentPair, setCurrentPair] = useState(false);

    const Data = new Date();
    const Hour = Data.getHours();
    const Minutes = Data.getMinutes();
    const currentData = Hour * 60 + Minutes;

    useEffect(() => {
        pairs.forEach((pair) => {
            const pairStartHour = pair.timeStart[0] + pair.timeStart[1];
            const pairStartMinutes = pair.timeStart[3] + pair.timeStart[4];

            const pairEndHour = pair.timeEnd[0] + pair.timeEnd[1];
            const pairEndMinutes = pair.timeEnd[3] + pair.timeEnd[4];

            const pairTimeStart =
                Number(pairStartHour) * 60 + Number(pairStartMinutes);

            const pairTimeEnd = Number(pairEndHour) * 60 + Number(pairEndMinutes);

            console.log(pairTimeStart);
            console.log(pairTimeEnd);
            console.log(currentData);

            if (pairTimeStart <= currentData <= pairTimeEnd) {
                setCurrentPair(true);
            } else {
                setCurrentPair(false);
            }
        });
    }, []);

    console.log(currentPair);

    return (
        <div className={styles.mainContentContainer}>
            {pairs.map((pair, index) => (
                <div key={index} className={styles.pairsContainer}>
                    <Link to={'/scheduleInfo:id' + index}>
                        <div
                            onClick={() => {
                                setShowSchedule(false);
                                setShowInfo(true);
                            }}
                            className={styles.pair}>
                            <div className={styles.headPair}>
                                <div className={styles.headLeft}>
                                    <span
                                        className={
                                            currentPair
                                                ? styles.currentPair
                                                : styles.numPair
                                        }>
                                        {index + 1}
                                    </span>
                                    <h3 className={styles.type}>{pair.type}</h3>
                                </div>
                                <span className={styles.time}>
                                    {pair.timeStart} - {pair.timeEnd}
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            <div className={styles.infoPair}>
                                <div className={styles.namePair}>{pair.name}</div>
                                <div className={styles.teachPair}>{pair.teacher}</div>
                                <div className={styles.classRoomPair}>
                                    {pair.classRoom}
                                </div>
                                <div className={styles.groupPair}>
                                    {pair.group} подгруппа
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Link>
                </div>
            ))}
            <Link to={'/'}>
                <button className={styles.btn}>Выйти</button>
            </Link>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим, как один из вариантов, написать функцию, которая будет возвращать нужный стиль в зависимости от переданного времени начала и окончания мероприятия

```
/**
 * @param {string} start
 * @param {string} end
 */
function checkDate(start, end) {
  const now = new Date();
  const h = now.getHours();
  const m = now.getMinutes();
  const startTime = start.split(':').map( i => Number(i));
  if (startTime[0] > h) return styles.INACTIVE;
  const endTime = end.split(':').map( i => Number(i));
  if (endTime[0] <= h) {
    if (startTime[1] < m) return styles.INACTIVE;
    if (startTime[1] >= m && endTime[1] <= m) return styles.ACTIVE;
  }
  return styles.INACTIVE;
}
```

внутри вашего map в нужном месте вставляете эту функцию()

```
return (
    {pairs.map((pair, index) => (
        // какой то код
        <div key={index} className={checkDate(pair.timeStart, pair.timeEnd)}>
        // какой то код
    )}
)
```

Это как один из способов.
Если проверка легкая, то можно прям внутри className={} проверят условия
Для примера

```
<div key={index} className={pair.active ? 'active' : 'inactive'}>
```

P.S. Функцию, возможно, придется подтюнить, детально не тестировал

Comment: Большое спасибо за ваш ответ) Но к сожалению он для всех занятий делает стиль инактив. При этом я поменял время в своей OC. Но увы и ах((

Comment: Хотя нет, прошу прощения, все действительно работает))) Но у меня есть еще разделения на подгруппы, хотелось бы чтобы было еще и разделение на подгруппы)

Comment: Я вам предложил вариант, как идею, как это можно реализовать. А уже конкретной реализацией проверок по вашим условиям - это уже вы сами. Добавьте проверки в нужные вам места, напишите новый функции проверки условий, простые проверяйте вторым способом.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)

Comment: Будут проблемы с конкретной реализацией проверок, приходите, попробуем помочь их реализовать